# Probability Integral Transform: Proof it is distributed on $U (0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning

I have worked out the proof for this question but wanted to check if my intuition also holds here. Please see below for the brief proof and then my proposed explanation:

For a continuous random variable, $X$, with cdf, $F(x)$, then if we define a continuous random variable

$ U = F(X)$, then $U \thicksim U(0,1)$

For the proof, we need to show that $P(U \le u) = u$

$F(U) = P(U \le u)\\ 
= P(F(X) \le u)\\ 
= P\big(F^{-1}\left(F(X)\right) \le F^{-1}(u)\big)\\
= P\big(F^{-1}(U) \le F^{-1}(u) \big)\\
= F\big( F^{-1}(U)\big)\\
= u $

My question relates to whether this argument holds and I would appreciate if someone could explain if it doesnt:

$U \thicksim (0,1)$ and since (i) $u \in [0,1]$ and (ii) $F(U)$ is monotonic increasing, then $F(U) = P(U \le u) = u$

I am sure this probably isn't correct but would really appreciate if someone could point out where this does not hold as I rationalised this before solving the actual equation, so feel it was a more intuitive understanding.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your argument is valid only if $F$ is strictly monotone so that $F^{-1}$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF $F$ is strictly monotone increasing, the argument of the OP is correct. If not, then we have to consider the alternative to $F^{-1}$. This can be achieved by using the quantile function of $X$.
$$ Q(t)=\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}: F(x)\geq t\}\quad\text{where}\quad 0<t<1$$

It can be proven that
$$ F(x)\geq t\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad Q(t)\leq x$$
This equivalency implies that $F(Q(t))\geq t$ in general. However, if and that $F$ is continuous at $Q(t)$, then for any $s<Q(t)$,  $F(s)<t$. Taking limit as $s\nearrow Q(t)$ gives $F(Q(t))=t$.

Since $F$ is continuous by assumption, $F(x)=\lim\limits_{y\nearrow x}F(y)=F(x-)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, if $U=F(X)$
$$\begin{align}
P[U<u]=P[F(X)<u]=P[X<Q(u)]=F(Q(u))=u
\end{align}$$
This is enough to conclude that $U$ is uniform distributed over $(0,1)$.